# Unity camera clip

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, glsl, shader, clip

I've created an orthographic camera in Unity and try to render a quad. Here is a shader:

```
Shader "TestShader"
{
    Properties
    {
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Pass
        {
            GLSLPROGRAM
            #include "UnityCG.glslinc"

            #ifdef VERTEX

            void main()
            {
                gl_Position = gl_Vertex;
            }

            #endif

            #ifdef GEOMETRY

            layout(triangles) in;
            layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 15) out;

            void main()
            {
                gl_Position = vec4(-1, -1, 0, 1); EmitVertex();
                gl_Position = vec4(-1, 1, 0, 1); EmitVertex();
                gl_Position = vec4(1, 1, 0, 1); EmitVertex();
                EndPrimitive();

                gl_Position = vec4(-1, -1, 0, 1); EmitVertex();
                gl_Position = vec4(1, 1, 0, 1); EmitVertex();
                gl_Position = vec4(1, -1, 0, 1); EmitVertex();
                EndPrimitive();
            }


            #endif

            #ifdef FRAGMENT

            void main()
            {
                gl_FragColor = vec4(0.5);
                gl_FragDepth = 0.5;
            }

            #endif

            ENDGLSL
        }
    }
}
```

So, I expect this camera would always fill all screen space with gray color, independent of where the quad is in world space.

But it seems, that if the quad in world space is out of (camera.nearClipPlane, camera.farClipPlane) clipping planes, I don't see anything on the screen.

I am ALWAYS setting z coordinate = 0 (normalized device coordinate) in geometry shader! And it seems that Unity perform it's own cliping before sending the vertices to OpenGL.. But it's nonsense!